# RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not scrolling smoothly

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to know for all api NOT all api (min 16) because RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not scrolling smoothly. I search on Google, stackover, ect. I found a lot of solution but all are not working on my phone. I try using

1. `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`
2. `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`
3. `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

All of them are not working on my phone (5.1.1) . My project is min (16)

**Here is my xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGray">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_nearby_places"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_click"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_search"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Nearby Places"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Here are 8 ways"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_ways"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_type_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Breakfast"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_type_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.6dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/see_more_type_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="See More"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_type_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Lunch"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_type_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.6dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/see_more_type_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="See More"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_type_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Dinner"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_type_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.6dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorGrayDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/see_more_type_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="See More"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGrayDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is Activity**

```
        recycler_view_ways = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_ways);
        recycler_view_type_1 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_type_1);
        recycler_view_type_2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_type_2);
        recycler_view_type_3 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_type_3);
        recycler_view_ways.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        recycler_view_type_1.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        recycler_view_type_2.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        recycler_view_type_3.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));           
        recycler_view_ways.setAdapter(new WaysRVAdapter(MainActivity.this, waysList));
....
```

Comment: where are you setting recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` should be work. and try to use `NestedScrollView`

Comment: @Ratilal Chopda **setLayoutManager** and then **setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)** then **setAdapter**

Comment: also why did you put all recycler view inside a extra Linear Layout

Comment: @Abhishek Singh because above **recyclerview** have **TextView for different type name** and below **TextView for see more**.  I only show short way in this.

Comment: why are you not using single recyclerview with recyclerview as item type?

Comment: if your parent linearlayout already have vertical orientation. then what is the need of all the other linear layout again with vertical orientation... what exactly you want to achieve ?????

Comment: @Divyesh Patel it have a lot of type (breakfast, lunch, dinner, etc..). So I use different recyclerview. For eg, one type have different restaurants can't use single recyclerview.

Comment: use multiple recyclerview inside single recyclerview. Set adpater inside of Onbinder of main recycler.

Comment: Use NestedScrollView instead.